# Deux points, dialogue et guillemets

Tags: grammaire, typographie, ponctuation, dialogues

Dans l'extrait suivant:

> Elle dit :
>   — Voilà cette chose, Nicolas.
>   — Merci Caroline.
>   — De rien.

Est-ce que cet extrait a une construction correcte ou a-t-on besoin de mettre des guillemets ? Doit-on mettre un tiret au premier dialogue ?

Combien de phrases comportent cet extrait ? Est-ce une seule grosse phrase ? J'ai du mal à croire qu'on puisse finir une phrase par un `:`.

J'ai vu un exemple de ce style dans un exercice de CE1 et je suis assez perplexe.

Comment: Je me suis permis de changer les traits d'union en tirets sur quadratin, puisque ce n'était pas l'objet de la question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pour ce qui est des guillemets, on trouve les deux formes dans la littérature :

- Sans guillemets

  > Texte ne constituant pas un dialogue.
  >    — Début du dialogue, simple phrase, et sans guillemets.
  >    — Poursuite du dialogue, autre phrase.
  >    — Fin du dialogue, encore une phrase.
  >   Reprise du texte ne constituant pas un dialogue.

  [Zola – *Thérèse Raquin*, page 28](http://books.google.fr/books?id=5oItAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA28)
  [Zola – *Au bonheur des dames*, vol. 1, page 11](http://books.google.fr/books?id=v_9WjTkyYmAC&pg=PA11)
- Avec guillemets

  > Texte ne constituant pas un dialogue. « Début du dialogue initié par une phrase.
  >    — Poursuite du dialogue, autre phrase.
  >    — Fin du dialogue, encore une phrase. » Reprise du texte ne constituant pas un dialogue.

  [Proust – *Du côté de chez Swann*, page 12](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Ks3g0-RJVTUC&pg=PA12)

Je n'ai pas vu, par contre, de dialogue commençant à la fois par un guillemet et un tiret. Cela semble confirmé par [Wikipédia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret#Tiret_long), mais sans que je ne puisse déterminer s'il s'agit d'une règle ou non.

Quant aux deux-points, je suis perplexe. Effectivement, il ne doit pas s'agir d'une phrase puisque la fonction de deux-points est de séparer une phrase en membres. Qu'en est-il lorsqu'il s'agit d'introduire un dialogue alors que ce dernier est lui-même constitué de phrases distinctes ? Je n'ai pas trouvé la réponse.

Answer (score 5):

Selon le *[Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence%3aLexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale)* (éd. 2002) :

> Suite de citations, les dialogues inclus dans un texte seront ouverts et clos par des guillemets. Les changements d'interlocuteurs seront marqués par des moins (tirets).

En ce qui concerne les deux points :

> Le *deux points* introduit une explication, une citation ou un discours.
>
> Chaque paragraphe d'une énumération introduite par un deux points, sauf le dernier, se termine par un point virgule, quelle que soit sa ponctuation interne.

Donc d'après l'exemple que tu donnes j'écrirais :

> Elle dit :
>     « — Voilà cette chose, Nicolas ;
>      — Merci Caroline ;
>      — De rien. »

Mais je dois dire que spontanément j'aurais mis une virgule et pas un point virgule à la fin des deux premières répliques.

Spontanément j'ai aussi mis un tiret long à la place des tirets courts ; rien sur la longueur des  tirets dans mon édition du *[Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale.](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence%3aLexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale)*

Quant au nombre de phrases, je pense qu'il y en a une seule (qui se composerait de quatres propositions indépendantes ?), mais j'attends de lire ce que d'autres en pensent.

Comment: Est-ce qu'un dialogue est considéré comme une énumération?

Comment: Pour les tirets, la page [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiret) sur le tiret fait la différence entre tous les tirets. De plus, la [page de manuel](http://bepo.fr/wiki/Manuel#Tirets) du projet Bépo en fait une synthèse assez bonne.

Comment: @ Nikko : certainement pas, mais pourrait-on dire qu'un dialogue est une énumération de citations ? Après réflexion, non. Je pense donc que dans le dialogue que tu cites les points ne posent effectivement pas de problème et que chaque citation des personnages est donc bien une phrase à elle seule.

Comment: ":" pourrait alors finir une phrase?

Comment: C'est la première fois que je vois dire que les changements d'interlocuteurs sont marqués par "des moins tirets". J'ai toujours lu qu'il fallait choisir entre les tirets semi-cadratins (`--` en LaTeX) ou cadratins (`---`).

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour, alors non à l'ouverture de guillemets il ne peut avoir un tiret ! Voilà^^ (pour le reste je ne saurais pas répondre)

Comment: Aurais-tu des sources ? Plus pertinentes que la référence dans ce domaine, à savoir : « Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale »